# CakePHP2.0 What is the correct way to access post variables in a CakePHP controller?

Tags: ajax, post, cakephp-2.0

I am unsure as to how I access variables that I have posted using ajax in my controller. I though it might be something along the lines of:

```
$this->request->data['post']['varName'];
```

I don't think that is the correct way to access the variables I have posted as it doesn't seem to work, so my question is: "What is the correct way to access post variables in a CakePHP controller". For completeness I will include an example jQuery ajax call. If you could refer how to access the data with the example below that would be great

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST",
         url: "someURL", // Not an actual URL just placeholder for example
         data: {'foo': 5, 'bar': 12},
         success: function()
                  {
                       alert('Post was successful');
                  }
          });
```

So how would I access foo and bar in a cakePHP controller?

Also if you know where to find this information in the documentation could you please link me to it as I had a hard time finding the information.

**Update!**

Found the link to the documentation [here.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-post-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `$this->request-data['post']['varName'];` a typo? If not, then you have a syntax error after the request property where you need a `->`.

I think your problem could be solved by using this though:

```
echo $this->request->data['foo']; // Should print 5
echo $this->request->data['bar']; // Should print 12
```

Comment: Sorry yeah it was a type, I'll edit it now. Ok I will have a go at that method.